# Is there any current implementation of a middleware that creates an activity based on W3C Trace Context for dotnet?

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights, w3c, open-telemetry, telemetry

I'm trying to find a way to have my controllers automatically create the activity based on  w3c headers.
My request has the traceparent header.

I am not using AppInsights, and I know that if I instrument them I should get that, but my current service doesn't use that and I still want to create that Activity on every request.

Is there any library that handles those things, or should I just create middleware to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically, however, Activities are only generated if you're listening to the `ActivitySource` for the Activity.

For OpenTelemetry, if you're using the `OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore` package, and added that to the OpenTelemetry Setup, that should output the Activities.

Take a look at the docs here. https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/getting-started/